# Coinbase API returns 401 for POST

Tags: c#, api, coinbase-api

I'm trying to use Coinbase's API to sell crypto currency, and I keep getting  401 errors. The below code works for all of the GET methods I've tried so far, but I can't figure out where I'm going wrong with the POST.

```
    private static string GetWebResponse(string url, string command, string path, string body)
    {
        var timeStamp = EpochSeconds;
        var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);

        request.Method = command;
        request.ContentType = "application/json";
        request.Headers.Add("CB-VERSION", VersionDate);
        request.Headers.Add("CB-ACCESS-KEY", ApiKey);
        request.Headers.Add("CB-ACCESS-SIGN", GetAccessSign(timeStamp, command, path, body));
        request.Headers.Add("CB-ACCESS-TIMESTAMP", timeStamp);

        if (command == "POST")
        {
            using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(request.GetRequestStream()))
            {
                streamWriter.Write(body);
                streamWriter.Flush();
                streamWriter.Close();
            }
        }

        var response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();

        using (var reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream(), Encoding.ASCII))
        {
            return reader.ReadToEnd();
        }
    }

    private static string GetAccessSign(string timestamp, string command, string path, string body)
    {
        var hmacKey = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(ApiSecret);

        string data = timestamp + command + path + body;
        using (var signatureStream = new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(data)))
        {
            return new HMACSHA256(hmacKey).ComputeHash(signatureStream).Aggregate(new StringBuilder(), (sb, b) => sb.AppendFormat("{0:x2}", b), sb => sb.ToString());
        }
    }
```

I figure something is wrong with the body of the POST request, but it looks right to me.

EDIT:

I'm going to show how the body is formed for clarification...

```
            var body = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(
            new
            {
                commit = "false",
                amount = Math.Round(sellAmount, 8).ToString(),
                currency = "BTC",
                payment_method = fiatWalletId
            });
```

EDIT 2:

I tried all the same stuff as before, but using RestSharp, and it returns a more specific error:

```
{\"errors\":[{\"id\":\"authentication_error\",\"message\":\"invalid signature\"}]}
```

EDIT 3:

This API key is set up for all permissions / scopes, including the ones I need for this request:

`wallet:accounts:create`
`wallet:accounts:delete`
`wallet:accounts:read`
`wallet:accounts:update`
`wallet:addresses:create`
`wallet:addresses:read`
`wallet:buys:create`
`wallet:buys:read`
`wallet:checkouts:create`
`wallet:checkouts:read`
`wallet:contacts:read`
`wallet:deposits:create`
`wallet:deposits:read`
`wallet:notifications:read`
`wallet:orders:create`
`wallet:orders:read`
`wallet:orders:refund`
`wallet:payment-methods:delete`
`wallet:payment-methods:limits`
`wallet:payment-methods:read`
`wallet:sells:create`
`wallet:sells:read`
`wallet:transactions:read`
`wallet:transactions:request`
`wallet:transactions:send`
`wallet:transactions:transfer`
`wallet:user:email`
`wallet:user:read`
`wallet:user:update`
`wallet:withdrawals:create`
`wallet:withdrawals:read`

Comment: 401 is unauthorised so I assume you've checked your api key is correct etc?

Comment: Try the simplest possible request, perhaps a GET request for time and see if that works. https://developers.coinbase.com/api/v2#time

Comment: I can do GETs on my wallet on Coinbase, so I know the request is well-formed, and it passes authorization for GET requests (with no body) so I would expect it has something to do with the json body.

Comment: Your conclusion is incorrect.  401 is `unauthorized`.  What API are you calling?  Please identify the specific URL(s).  Coinbase has a permissions system, so it is entirely possible the account you are using does not have the proper permissions set up for the POST calls.

Comment: See [my answer on a related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47835432/get-coinbase-wallet-list-with-restsharp-library/47835519#47835519) to see what I mean.  You need to add the proper scopes to your account, so you can call the POST methods.  I haven't used Coinbase or its API, I just think this is something I've seen before.  Not 100% positive this explains your issue.

Comment: 3 years late, but I was having this same issue, GET was fine POST was not. I am using the coinbase pro api, and forgot to add the request body to the pre-hash when generating my signature. re: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69759336/6448060

Answer (score 0):

The solution for me was that I forgot to put **/v2** (/v2 + some path) in the path part of the signature and the signature was bad, the response was misleading though saying unauthorized.